# Lambda expression in place of a left join

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I try to convert T-SQL to lambda expression but I met a problem. Data is not correct.

This is my query

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT UserId, MIN(ID) AS ID 
     FROM FingerMachineUsers  
     GROUP BY UserId ) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    FingerTimeSheets B ON A.ID = B.UserNo 
                       AND B.DayOfCheck = '2018-08-02 00:00:00.000'
WHERE 
    B.UserNo IS NULL
```

This is my lambda expression

```
dbContext.FingerMachineUsers
         .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
         .Select(g => new { ID = g.Min(p => p.ID), UserId=g.Select(p => p.UserId) })
         .GroupJoin(dbContext.FingerTimeSheets.Where(x=>x.DayOfCheck==shortDate),x=>x.ID,y=>y.UserNo,(x,y)=> new { ID = x, UserNo = y })
         .SelectMany(x=>x.UserNo.DefaultIfEmpty(),(x,y)=>new { x.ID,y.UserNo});
```

Data returned is not correct.

Comment: It's a **lambda** (yes - b before d) expression - not a "lamda" ...

Comment: Here's a few tools that keep headaches like this away:

https://www.linqpad.net/

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: Can `FingerTimeSheets.UserNo` be `NULL` or `B.UserNo IS NULL` only means that the join failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linq query should be:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

var innerQuery = from x in db.FingerMachineUsers
                    group x.UserId by x.UserId into y
                    select new { UserId = y.Key, ID = y.Min() };

var query = from x in innerQuery
            join y in db.FingerTimeSheets on x.ID equals y.UserNo into z
            from y in z.Where(a => a.DayOfCheck == date).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where y == null || y.UserNo == null
            select x;
```

The query is more or less equivalent to:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [UserId], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [K1], 
        MIN([Extent1].[UserId]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[FingerMachineUsers] AS [Extent1]
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[UserId] ) AS [GroupBy1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[FingerTimeSheets] AS [Extent2] ON (([GroupBy1].[A1] = [Extent2].[UserNo]) OR (([GroupBy1].[A1] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[UserNo] IS NULL))) AND ([Extent2].[DayOfCheck] = @p__linq__0)
    WHERE [Extent2].[TimeSheetId] IS NULL OR [Extent2].[UserNo] IS NULL
```

(where `TimeSheetId` is the primary key of `FingerTimeSheets`)

There are some open points about the nullability of `FingerTimeSheets.UserNo` and about the meaning of `B.UserNo IS NULL`. Is `FingerTimeSheets.UserNo` nullable? Then the query is correct as is. If `FingerTimeSheets.UserNo` isn't nullable then change the `where` to:

```
where y == null
```

Another small problem that needs fixing is if both `FingerMachineUsers.ID` is nullable and `FingerTimeSheets.UserNo` is nullable. Change the moddile `from y in z.Where()` to:

```
from y in z.Where(a => UserNo != null && a.DayOfCheck == date).DefaultIfEmpty()
```